# Service code to get Xperia model

Tags: dialer-codes, system-info, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I'd like to check the manufacturing date of an Xperia Ray. The easy way is by looking at the sticker under the battery, but I'm trying to convey this to a potential seller, and I would prefer something that doesn't involve taking apart the phone. I've read on Yahoo answers that `*#9999#` should do it, but it's normally a Nokia [service code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_service_codes) so I doubt the accuracy. I've also found `*#*#4636#*#*` (info) and `*#*#7378423#*#*` (service), which may have what I need inside of a menu. Can anyone give me a more reliable answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Xperia™ Function Tester App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.androidapp.functiontester&feature=search_result&hl=en)

I would suggest trying this official application to find out the information you needed.

Comment: I think this is the same as one of the codes (which though?). I would need confirmation that the production date is mentioned.

Comment: Not sure this method reliable or not.

[Analysis of IMEI numbers](http://www.numberingplans.com/?page=analysis&sub=imeinr)

Input IMEI, then check against Est. Date of Range Issuance.

Answer (score 0):

On my Xperia Z2 this code works: `*#*#SERVICE#*#*` type into dialer and a menu would appear.